# Erro em lista encadeada C puro

Tags: c, lista-encadeada

Estou fazendo uma lista encadeada simples onde a struct possui apenas uma variável inteira 'dado', o usuário digita o dado a ser inserido logo no menu e ele é jogado na função que adiciona um novo elemento no inicio da minha lista encadeada. Porém ele fica jogando o erro que novo_element ainda não foi inializado, justo na linha onde ele recebe o dado.

```
/*corpo da minha struct
struct lista
{
    int dado;
    lista* proximo;
}; */


void inserir_inicio(int numero)
{
    lista* novo_elemento;

    novo_elemento->dado = numero; // onde acontece o erro using uninitialized memory

    if (head == NULL)
    {
        head = novo_elemento;
        head->proximo = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        novo_elemento->proximo = head;
        head = novo_elemento;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sim, `novo_elemento` é um ponteiro para `lista`. Aloque memória para a struct (vide função malloc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você apenas declarou o ponteiro novo_elemento, está faltando alocar a memória para este ponteiro.

```
novo_elemento = (lista*) malloc(sizeof(lista));
```

Comment: `malloc` retorna um ponteiro do tipo `void`, tem que fazer um `cast` pro tipo do ponteiro do dado